# Attach POST data to BackgroundDownloader

Tags: post, background, windows-phone-8.1, microsoft-metro

I am implementing a Windows Phone 8.1 application that creates BackgroundDownloaders to restore cloud files back to the phone.

The cloud requires to POST the **file ID** as an additional JSON POST request and i cannot find a way to define it the BackgroundDownloader object.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The way to do it is by creating a temp file to hold the JSON post data and send it to the CreateDownload function (as the last StorageFile parameter).

In addition, i added a Content-Type header to describe it (for me it is application/x-www-form-urlencoded) and add it with SetRequestHeader.

```
//set the Content-Type header

BackgroundDownloader^ downloader = ref new BackgroundDownloader();
Platform::String^ SKey2 = ref new Platform::String(L"Content-Type");
Platform::String^ SValue2 = ref new Platform::String(L"application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
downloader->SetRequestHeader(SKey2, SValue2);

//Create a temporary file and write the POST data into it

StorageFile^ postDataFile = nullptr;
....

//Call CreateDownload with the postDataFile
downloader->CreateDownload(uri, file, postDataFile);
```

That worked for me.